# Raster map calculation

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator

I figured out a way to filter a raster by using the r.mapcalculator or the raster calculator. The problem is that I have to use Qgis 2.2 because some of my models doesn't work with 2.4. In 2.2 the raster calculator doesn't work within models. So I have to use the r.mapcalc tool.

...now to my problem...

My raster file is full of useless grids (extreme values) which I want to filter by condiotions. First I created maps <2*STDV and >2STDV. Now I wanted to use the following string "ifelse(A

I hope you understand my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use if(statement, value_if_true, value_if_false) with r.mapcalc. see [here](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.mapcalc.html) for more details

```
r.mapcalc result='if( (a<2*std)||(a>2*std), null(), a)'
```

Comment: This got flagged for length and content. Maybe you can extend it, add an example, maybe some capital letters?

Comment: I've added an example. HTH.